# Emulate ios with live reload not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I got problem with live reload in ionic. Here is what I exactly did:

console code:

```
ionic start myApp tabs 
cd myApp
ionic emulate ios -lc
//here is everything working fine
```

and after that I do:

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
ionic emulate ios -lc
```

after this ionic app never show up I can see only splash screen still loading. You can see on screen shot: 
[image]

Comment: Are you connected to the same WiFi network as the computer?

Comment: Also please check for errors in the system logs. Simulator top menu: Device -> Open System Log (or CMD + /). Edit the main post with any errors you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<allow-navigation />` tag in your config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Or for security, only assign your local `dev server` to href, something like below:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.158:8100" />
```

And change the ip and port to your own and ensure the value of href can be visit in your browser.